# $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ depending on finite coordinates is $\alpha$-Holder

Tags: continuity

Let $M = \{1, \dots, n\}$ be a metric space with the metric $d$ and, in $\Omega = M^{\mathbb{N}}$, define $\tilde{d}(x, y) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{d(x_k, y_k)}{2^k}$.

We say that $f\colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ depens only on finite coordinates if there exist $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_1, x_2, \dots) = f(x_1, \dots, x_m)$.

I'm trying to show that f $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ depends only on finite coordinates, then $f$ is $\alpha$-Holder

Comment: What if $\tilde d(x,y)<2^{-m}$? This question isn't really suitable for MathOverflow - probably it would be more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: what is $A(x_1,\dots)$?

Comment: Sorry! It’s f...

Comment: But even if $f$ only depends on the first coordinate, $f(x_1)$, in general it will not be Hölder